# Analysing Mautic database schema

Tags: database, mautic

I recently installed Mautic open source on my pc. I want to analyse how the data is getting stored into it (DB schema or DB files). I want to know where my data is getting stored after I enter the details.

Answer (score 1):

it's a little more complex than you might first imagine. Luckily InnoDB is in use with a lot of foreign keys making it easy to map out.

Using a tool like MySQL Workbench you can "Reverse Engineer Database" and get something like this from a typical mautic install:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuQYK.jpg

Unfortunately it's terrible at auto-arranging things to be legible. However, if you do this yourself with MySQL Workbench you can hover over the data portions you need, and the connections will be highlighted... you can then arrange to your needs and ignore everything else.